# Remove headers from Email Body

Tags: php, email, header, content-type

I am having trouble with email synchronization application, i am developing an conversation module for my project so i had extracted email body and attachments from the Email Account but problem is i also got some header text in email body like

```
"--PHP-alt-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7 Content-Type: text/plain --PHP-alt-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7 "
```

and i want to remove it

actual output is

```
--PHP-alt-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7 Content-Type: text/plain --PHP-alt-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7 Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="PHP-related-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7" --PHP-related-9ce0b24f8d52c4d37de61cb315107795d140f8b7 Content-Type: text/html Dear Milind

Thank you for choosing XXXXX for your limo hire.

Please accept this e-mail as confirmation the following booking has been
confirmed and requires you to print, sign and return the attached
contract with us, either by e-mail, fax or post, within 3 days.
To view contract for booking please click here
We would like to draw your attention to our agreed Terms and
Conditions concerning the booking and ask that you ensure you comply,
which can be found on our website www.xxxxx.co.uk

If this has been received in error, please contact our Office
immediately on XXXXXXX or XXXXXX.

Regards
Company name
TEL:
```

and i want something like

```
Dear Milind

    Thank you for choosing XXXXX for your limo hire.

    Please accept this e-mail as confirmation the following booking has been
    confirmed and requires you to print, sign and return the attached
    contract with us, either by e-mail, fax or post, within 3 days.
    To view contract for booking please click here
    We would like to draw your attention to our agreed Terms and
    Conditions concerning the booking and ask that you ensure you comply,
    which can be found on our website www.xxxxx.co.uk

    If this has been received in error, please contact our Office
    immediately on XXXXXXX or XXXXXX.

    Regards
    Company name
    TEL:
```

i have tried `substr()` but its not that helpful
any regular expression may be?
here is code for email sending
lets assume body string = `$email_message` where all email format is written in "string"
PS: please note that some emails contains attachments

```
$subject = 'A sample email - Dual Format plus attachment plus inline';

// Create a boundary string.  It needs to be unique (not in the text) so ...
// We are going to use the sha1 algorithm to generate a 40 character string:
$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

// Define the headers we want passed.
$headers = "From: StarLimosine <sender@gmail.com> \r\n X-Mailer: Custom PHP Script";
//$headers.="\r\nCc:sender@gmail.com";
$headers.="\r\nBcc:sender@gmail.com , sender@gmail.in";
// Add in our primary content boundary, and mime type specification:
$headers .= 
    "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-{$sep}\"";

// Prepare our attachment file - Read it in, encode it and split it
//$attached = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));

// Also now prepare our inline image - Also read, encode, split:
$inline = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('images/Logo.png')));

// Now the body of the message.
$body =<<<EOBODY
--PHP-mixed-{$sep}
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-{$sep}"

--PHP-alt-{$sep}
Content-Type: text/plain


--PHP-alt-{$sep}
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="PHP-related-{$sep}"

--PHP-related-{$sep}
Content-Type: text/html

$email_message
<strong>
Star Limousines<br/>
TEL: 0800 9 556 556 <br/>
or 01435 813494</strong><br/>
<span style="font-size:10px">Registerd Office Pick Hill Farm, Horam East Sussex TN21 0JR</span>

--PHP-mixed-{$sep}--
EOBODY;
$body=$email_message;

mail($to,$subject,$body);
```

Comment: The problem lies in your email extraction approach then. Use a proper MIME library instead of trying to fix it afterwards.

Comment: can you please describe more or give me URL or something ?

Comment: You should not be generating mime emails yourself. [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) and [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) do that for you with FAR less code.

Comment: Thank Everyone for help, The PHPMailer Worked for me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any point of time, the headers are in the first two lines right? If that's the case, you can go with this:

```
substr($email, strpos($email, PHP_EOL, strpos($email, PHP_EOL) + 1));
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen its helpful it fixed some of my issues but not all

Answer (score 0):

add this only when you POST data when using GET remove this.

```
$headers .= 
    "\r\nContent-Type: text/html; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-{$sep}\"";
```

you will get response without headers